# Storing Random Data in MySQL (directly in table)

Tags: python, mysql, security

In a Python script, I'm generating a scrypt hash using a salt made up of data from os.urandom and I would like to save these in a MySQL table.  If I attempt to use the standard method I've seen used for efficiently storing hashes in a database, using a CHAR column, I get "Incorrect string value:" errors for both the hash and the salt.  The only data type I've been able to find that allows the random data is blob, but since blobs are stored outside the table they have obvious efficiency problems.

What is the proper way to do this?  Should I do something to the data prior to INSERTing it into the db to massage it into being accepted by CHAR?  Is there another MySQL datatype that would be more appropriate for this?

Edit:

Someone asked for code, so, when I do this:

```
salt = os.urandom(255)
hash = scrypt.hash(password,salt,1<<15,8,1,255)
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (email,hash,salt) values (%s,%s,%s)", [email,hash,salt])
```

MySQL gives me the "Incorrect string value" errors when I attempt to insert these values.

Edit 2:

As per Joran's request, here is the schema that doesn't like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `email` varchar(254) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hash` char(255) NOT NULL,
  `salt` char(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: ignore my answer it was totally wrong ... can you post your schema? and make sure you have utf8 encoding setup on the sql database

Comment: I assume that MySQL is complaining about unprintable characters, did you try to base64 encode the binary data?

Comment: Or use https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html

Comment: Jasper's answer worked (using the binary datatype)!  Make it into a proper answer and I'll mark it as answered!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your hash is a binary value that most likely will contain "unprintable characters" if it is interpreted as a string. To store arbitrary binary data, use [the BINARY or VARBINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/binary-varbinary.html) data type.

If you have to use a string datatype, you can use [base64 encoding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) to convert arbitrary data to an ASCII string.